# How to call recursive function after execute async.each

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, recursion

Anyone suggests me how can I trigger recursive function after executing the  async.each.I have done the logic by following

```
function recursive(aggs, callback) {
async.each(datas, function(data, asynccallback) { 
    // after some process
    asynccallback(null, true); 
}, function(err, resultData) {
    //after execute the async.each I need to do the following
        if (resultData.flage) { 
            // flage true call recirsive 
            recursive(args, callback); 
        } else { 
            // flage flase means return the callback to called function
            callback(null, data) 
        }
});
```

}

When I try the above way I got

> error: callback was already called.

Can anyone guide me to achieve this?.Thanks in Advance

Comment: Please format your JavaScript so it's legible. Thanks!

Comment: Please provide inputs you are calling the function with, also I don't see "datas" defined anywhere.

Comment: @MananVaghasiya the "datas" is a list I need to call the same function after execute the async each.

Comment: async.each will never give resultData variable you are trying to use according to async documentation. Also consider posting full code or at least error with full stack trace if you want someone to be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try Lodash-recursive :

https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash-recursive

They provided you an example :

```
var assert = require('assert')
var recursive = require('lodash-recursive')

var nodes = [
  {
    value: 'alpha',
    children: [
      {
        value: 'beta'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    value: 'gamma'
  }
]

var newNodes = recursive.map(nodes, function (node, recursive, map) {
  if (node.children) recursive(node.children)
  return map(node)
}, function (node) {
  if (node.value == 'beta') node.valid = true
  return node
})

var expected = [
  {
    "value": "alpha",
    "children": [
      {
        "value": "beta",
        "valid": true
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "value": "gamma"
  }
]

assert.deepEqual(expected, newNodes)
```

Comment: thanks for ur response but I need to call the recursive function after all values are iterated.So pls could you help me to achieve it?

Comment: Maybe use a accumulator javascript : recursive(aggs, temporaryAccumulator ,callback) , callback must be call only once